# Aloe vera sickness

Tags: diagnosis

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzUrl.jpg)[image]
My aloevera plant was having black and brown spots on it. So I asked on gardening stack exchange for the same. ([Why is my aloe vera plant having plant spots?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/why-is-my-aloe-vera-plant-having-plant-spots?r=SearchResults)).
One answer suggested to cut the brown portion. So I did the same.
Now after 2-3 months the cutted plant is still having Brown spots.
Plz help me fix this iisue so that I can get an aloe vera without a spot.( Fully Green)
Weather Conditions: the winter here is retreating and it's getting warmer day by day.

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: India(South-Asia)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like one of the many fungal leaf spot infections that affect Aloe vera. Unfortunately, the plant may not recover, but remove it from its pot and inspect the roots to see if any are rotting. Remove any rotted rots and repot into clean potting soil, and try spraying with a fungicide, as well as keeping the plant out of any rain and only watering when essential to prevent shrivelling of the leaves; make sure you only water the soil in the pot and not the leaves. Further information here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/care-aloe-plant-dark-spots-94444.html